# Executar documento e enviar valor de variável em PHP pelo Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, variáveis

Olá, tenho que desenvolver um botão confirm para a deleção de um produto. Para isso, tive a ideia de executar um arquivo em php através do ajax a partir do momento que eu clico em "Confirmar" no confirm do JS, juntamente, passando o valor de uma variável que irá servir para fazer as sqls.

O problema e que não sei como faço para passar o valor dessa variável, nós exemplos que achei mostra-se como passar valores de inputs pelo id ou de valores já determinados, mas nada parecido com o que eu preciso.

PHP com o JS:

```
<?php
  $codprod = $_POST['produtoDelete'];// Esse é o valor que preciso para fazer as sqls

  //JS
  <script>
  function excluirConfirm() {
    var txt;
    var r = confirm("Tem certeza que deseja excluir esse produto?");
    if (r == true) {
        //Aqui fica o ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'produtoSessionEdit.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                codprod: ? //AQUI QUE ESTA MINHA DÚVIDA
            } /* ... */
        });

    }else {
        txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
  </script>
?>
```

Arquivo PHP com as sqls

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

$codprod = $_POST['produtoDelete'];

//Deleção do produto
$select= "DELETE DESCRICAO FROM PRODUTO WHERE COD_PRODUTO=:codd";
$result= $pdo->prepare($select);
$result->bindParam(':codd', $codprod);
$result->execute();

echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Produto excluido!"); </script>';
?>
```

O que posso fazer para sesolver isso?

Comment: Pelo oque eu entendi você quer pegar esse $codprod e enviar por ajax para a página php certo?

Comment: Exatamente. E também "chamar" a execuçao do arquivo, acredito que ja estou fazendo isso.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, remova o javascript da tag php

```
<?php
  $codprod = $_POST['produtoDelete'];// Esse é o valor que preciso para fazer as sqls ?>
```

Em seguida chamará a função excluir em um botão ou algo do tipo exemplo

```
<button onclick="excluirConfirm();">Botao</button>
```

no arquivo js você irá pegar o valor recebido em uma variavel js

```
//JS
  <script>
  function excluirConfirm() {
    var valorRecebido = <?php echo $codprod; ?>;
    var txt;
    var r = confirm("Tem certeza que deseja excluir esse produto?");
    if (r == true) {
        //Aqui fica o ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'produtoSessionEdit.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                codprod: valorRecebido //AQUI Você passará o valor e o codprod será o name
            } /* ... */
        });

    }else {
        txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
  </script>
```

Com isso no php você receberá pelo name dado no ajax

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

 //Aqui coloca o name dentro do post
$codprod = $_POST['codprod'];

//Deleção do produto
$select= "DELETE DESCRICAO FROM PRODUTO WHERE COD_PRODUTO=:codd";
$result= $pdo->prepare($select);
$result->bindParam(':codd', $codprod);
$result->execute();

echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Produto excluido!"); </script>';
?>
```

Comment: Quando faço dessa forma Anderson o confirm não aparece na tela.

Comment: Quando você faz oque que o confirm não funciona?

Comment: Quando comento as 2 linhas que foram adicionadas por ti, ele aparece.

Comment: Pode editar a sua pergunta com o código modificado fazendo um favor?

Comment: O código está da forma que vc colocou.

Comment: excluirConfirm(); perdão esqueci do ponto e virgula aqui, irei editar veja se era isso

Comment: Bom, não era isso.

Comment: irmão aqui está funcionando normal, só não funcionará a tag php mas chama a função normalmente olha https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjRJLW, você importo o javascript tudo certinho la no header?

Comment: Pois, nesse caso, ainda persiste meu problema de não conseguir passar o valor da varável php...

Comment: @AndersonAmorim veja se importou o javascript no header, de um alert dentro da função javascript e coloque o código atualizado

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63280/discussion-between-anderson-amorim-and-anderson-henrique).

Answer (score 1):

Sua variável php terá de ser armazenada no `client`, para que na submissão do formulário, o valor do `name` seja o nome da mesma no `php`, exemplo...

```
<form name="formEnv" id="env" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="produtoDelete" value="<?php echo $_POST['produtoDelete']?>">

    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $( "#env" ).submit(function( event ) {
         event.preventDefault();

         var r = confirm("Tem certeza que deseja excluir esse produto?");

         if(r == true) {

         var data = $("#env").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "suaPagina.php",
                data : data,
                dataType: "json",
                success : function(response){
                    if (response == 1) {

          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'sucesso';

                    };
                    if (response == 0) {

          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'falha';

                    };
                }
            })

           }else{alert('operação cancelada!');}
        });

})
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

$codprod = $_POST['produtoDelete'];

//Deleção do produto
$select= "DELETE DESCRICAO FROM PRODUTO WHERE COD_PRODUTO=:codd";
$result= $pdo->prepare($select);
$result->bindParam(':codd', $codprod);
$result->execute();

if($result){$retorno = 1}else{$retorno = 0};

echo json_encode($result)
exit();

?>
```

caso seu javascript seja imbutido na página, a variável php pode ser explícita.

Comment: Sua alternativa parece legal, como que eu faria para aplica-la usando confirm?

Comment: bom basta adiciona-lo antes da comunicação ajax, vou editar o código...